# Saving and Retrieving value from text box when submitted

Tags: php, html, textbox

I want to create a textbox, which can be edited and shows the text inside the textbox (hope that makes sense). I've managed to get the textbox and I have a submit button and everything. Since, however, I am still in the learning process with php and scripting, I don't know how I can then make this field show whatever was written. At the moment, whatever I type and submit vanishes when submitted (I know why that is, just not how to get the entered text to save to a txt file on the database or something.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is basically the whole script I have:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  include_once("include.inc.php");

  incHeader();



  // make sure staff only are here

  newbouncer(2);

   // include forum code
  include_once("forum-code.php");


mysql_query("UPDATE online SET location = 'My Preferences' WHERE userid = '" . $userID . "'") or die(mysql_error());


echo "</span></p> 


    </span>

<center><img src=\"/layout/images/notepad.png\"></center><p>
      ";

?>

<center><form action="/notes.php" method="post">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" style="width:380px;height:481px; padding:25px ;background:url('http://i686.photobucket.com/albums/vv221/LilyLoganBing/scrollnotes.png'); border:1px #000000">
To-Do's:


</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>

<?php

  incFooter();

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, the text inside the textarea is stored in `$_POST['comments']`.
After submission, you can do what ever you like.

Example how to store it in a MYSQL database. Put this piece of code in your form processing script, the script that will run after the submit button is pressed.

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES('.$_POST['comments'].')
```

To put the text in your MYSQL db back in te textarea use this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT text FROM comments'
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

   <teaxtarea name='comment'>$row['text']</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Whereabouts would I put that piece of code and how would I have it show up in the textbox?

Comment: the form processing script, would that be this part:

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be your answer

```
<?php

  session_start();

  include_once("include.inc.php");

  incHeader();



  // make sure staff only are here

  newbouncer(2);

   // include forum code
  include_once("forum-code.php");


$query = mysql_query("UPDATE online SET location = 'My Preferences' WHERE userid = '" . $userID . "'") or die(mysql_error());

$rs = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo "</span></p> 


    </span>

<center><img src=\"/layout/images/notepad.png\"></center><p>
      ";

?>

<center><form action="/notes.php" method="post">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" style="width:380px;height:481px; padding:25px ;background:url('http://i686.photobucket.com/albums/vv221/LilyLoganBing/scrollnotes.png'); border:1px #000000">

<?php echo $rs['comment']; ?> // field name from database, i.e comment

</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>

<?php

  incFooter();

  ?>
```